# Post By Tag (Tag Scoring)

Tags: discussion, tag-score

I was told that tag scores reflect the *answers* you have posted and their corresponding up/down votes.

So, while trolling my meta profile, I see that I have "post by tag" counts despite me having no answers posted on the site.

So why is asked questions being taken into account on the post by tag count, and not the tag score itself? It seems like it skews the ratio a bit, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hover the little score square, you will see that it shows scores individually for:

1. Questions, and
2. Answers

So, even if you don't have a answer tag score, you can still see scores for questions* (which doesn't count for the badges)*

[image: tagscore example]